# Loading object from .dat file

Tags: java

I'm having an issue loading objects back from my .dat file. I believe they're writing properly. I feel like the solution is pretty easy, but I've been banging my head against the wall for hours over this. Neither methods are throwing any errors. If I run the save2 method, my output is this:

```
Obj written: [Faculty] Professor John Example [x] 123-010-1010 [x] ID: 1 [x] Salary: $63,605.00
Obj written: [Student] Ron Doe [x] 123-222-2332 [x] Major: Culinary [x] ID: 2 [x] GPA: 3.7 [x] courseBag
Obj written: [Student] Bon Jovi [x] 123-372-4383 [x] Major: Computer Science [x] ID: 3 [x] GPA: 2.85 [x] courseBag
```

This is the output of running the load2 method:

```
FOUND A STUDENT---------
[PeopleBag]: Loaded people_bag2.dat into memory successfully.
```

But the objects aren't getting placed into memory. There's 1 faculty and 2 students that were saved. The load method isn't even picking up the faculty member.

Here's my save method:

```
public void save2() {
    String fileName;
    FileOutputStream outFile;
    ObjectOutputStream outStream;
    Person tempPerson;

    fileName = "people_bag2.dat";

    try {
        outFile = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);

        for (int i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
            if(personArray[i] != null) {
                tempPerson = personArray[i];
                outStream.writeObject(tempPerson); // this one line writes an object
                if(Utilities.DEBUG)
                    System.out.println("Obj written: "+tempPerson);
            }
        }

        outStream.close();
        if(Utilities.DEBUG)
            System.out.println("[PeopleBag]: Saved bag to "+fileName+" successfully.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Here's my load method:

```
public void load2() {
    String fileName;
    FileInputStream inFile;
    ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
    Student tempStudent;
    Faculty tempFaculty;

    fileName = "people_bag2.dat";

    try {
        inFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);

        while (true) {
            if(inStream.readObject().toString().startsWith("[Student")) {
                System.out.println("FOUND A STUDENT---------");

                tempStudent = (Student) inStream.readObject();
                Student person = new Student(tempStudent.getFirstName(), tempStudent.getLastName(), tempStudent.getPhoneNumber(), tempStudent.getMajor(), tempStudent.getCourseBag());
                add(tempStudent); //add(person) doesn't work either
                //if(Utilities.DEBUG)
                    System.out.println("tempStudent: "+tempStudent.toString() + "\n");

            }

            if(inStream.readObject().toString().startsWith("[Faculty")) {
                System.out.println("FOUND A FACULTY---------");

                tempFaculty = (Faculty) inStream.readObject();
                //String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String title, double salary
                Faculty f = new Faculty(tempFaculty.getFirstName(), tempFaculty.getLastName(), tempFaculty.getPhoneNumber(), tempFaculty.getTitle(), tempFaculty.getSalary());
                add(f); //add the person to the bag
            }

        }


    } catch (EOFException e) { // catch EOF
        try {
            if(Utilities.DEBUG)
                System.out.println("[PeopleBag]: Loaded "+fileName+" into memory successfully.");
            inStream.close();
        } exceptions blah blah

}
```

Also he add(Person... person) method works fine. I have a working method which loads the data from a text file. I have a similar method to load courses, except without the inStream.readObject().toString... if-statement, and it works fine. I think the issue has to do with the inStream.readObject().toString().startsWith( faculty or student).

This is a load method for courses, which works fine:

```
public void load() {
    String fileName = "course_bag.dat";
    FileInputStream inFile;
    ObjectInputStream inStream = null;
    Course tempCourse;

    try {
        inFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);

        while (true) {
            tempCourse = (Course)inStream.readObject();
            //String courseTitle, String crn, Textbook textbook, double credits
            Course txtbk = new Course(tempCourse.getCourseTitle(), tempCourse.getCrn(), tempCourse.getTextbook(), tempCourse.getCredits());
            add(txtbk);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File named "+ fileName +" not found.\n");
    } catch (EOFException e) { // catch EOF
        try {
            if(Utilities.DEBUG)
                System.out.println("[CourseBag]: Loaded "+fileName+" into memory successfully.");
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) { }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I love using JSON, but this is a project for school and it has to be done in this way.

Comment: @Gala I added more information, check my edit. I have another class using a similar method and it's working.

Comment: @Gala Neitther changing the technology nor the number of files nor the technique into a single file has anything to do with this problem. Please stop guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading an object and converting it to a string and throwing it away and seeing what the string starts with and then reading *another* object, you should read *one* object and use `instanceof` to see what it actually was.

Comment: Didn't even think of instanceof. Thank you!!